# How to get rid of desktops mini windows

Tags: windows, desktop

There are these mini desktop windows open on my computer. I cannot close them, and they interfere with other tasks that I'm doing.

I tried a web search to find the name of the process or service for these windows, without luck. I used task manager to try and find the process or service. The problem is that I don't know the name of these icons.

[image: Miniature desktop icons]

Comment: Please reopen this question. My problem isn't malware. It's these desktop minis. What is the name of them so I can kill the process using task manager on my Windows 11 machine? In fact, these two mini-windows prevent me from upgrading Malwarebytes. I can't click buttons because of the minis.

Comment: These are part of the shell. Sometimes, hover effects get stuck. You might want to try hovering the button that triggers them again to see if they will then disappear after you stop hovering it.

Comment: usually you just click on Desktop1 or the button that looks like a white square offset overt a black square, next to the search control on the windows task bar. you can usually also hit alt+Tab to close them. do none of those options work? if not, does logging out and back in help (actually logout, don't just lock and unlock)?